# ASP.NET MVC4 Routing - access controllers and actions with identical names using different routes

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

Using ASP.NET MVC4 Routing:

If I'd like to setup a Default routing configuration for the main section of the site:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Then another routing configuration, something similiar to the following:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "FOO",
            url: "FOO/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "FOO", action = "bar", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Notice the string "**FOO/**" in the url (just before the `/{controller...`

For example, I'd like to be able to access the main section of my site using a url like the following

`http://dummyurl.com/bar/1`

but then access controllers and actions that have identical names if I was to use

`http://dummyurl.com/**FOO**/bar/1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "FOO",
    url: "FOO/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "FOO", action = "bar", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

That route will result into something that you might not expect, **unless you have an mvc area named `FOO`**. That route will only work with `http://yourdomain/foo/foo/any_method_in_foo/id`

Comment: Areas is without question the better solution.

Answer (score 1):

Figured out by going through [***routing documentation by "the Gu"***](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/12/03/asp-net-mvc-framework-part-2-url-routing.aspx) that I simply needed to put:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "FOO",
        url: "FOO/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "FOO", action = "bar", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

Above:

```
     routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

in my `Routes.config` and blammo, good to go. I can now separate and access for example an Admin ("FOO") section in my project.